# Best way to order category names joined with children

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Say I have the following structure in a table:

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| category_id | name           | parent_id |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+
|           1 | foo            |         0 |
|           2 | bar            |         0 |
|           3 | baz            |         1 |
|           4 | test           |         2 |
|           5 | test1          |         3 |
|           6 | test2          |         5 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Does anyone have any pointers to achieve the following output:

```
foo
bar
foo > baz
bar > test
baz > test1
baz > test 1 > test2
```

I'm open to changing my schema if it helps, not sure if it is the best method to store the data?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what are you doing with the greater-than signs there?

Comment: @techjunkie.css these are supposed to be "arrows" indicating that the category to the left is a parent to the category to the right.

Comment: for 'baz > test1' and 'baz > test 1 > test2' why doesn't 'baz' have 'foo >' in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you want to have a look at [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

Answer (score 2):

You could try sorting by parent and then by name:

`SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY parent_id, name`

This will return all categories ordered by name, according to their level (parent).

Answer (score 1):

The [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) is a bit more complex to implement than a simple parent-child relationship, but it helps solve problems like this.